# Clone an EF6 record with relations

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm getting a record from EF6 with

```
Context
.MyRepo
.Include(p => p.MyRelation)
.AsNoTracking()
.SingleOrDefault(p => p.Uuid == recordUuid);
```

Then I try to insert a copy of the record zith

```
myRecord.Uuid = Guid.NewGuid();
myRecord.EntityKey = new System.Data.EntityKey("modelqualifiedname", "Id", 1726526);

Context.MyRepo.AddObject(myRecord);
Context.SaveChanges();
```

But it fails with this message

> "An object with the same key already exists in the ObjectStateManager.
>   The ObjectStateManager cannot track multiple objects with the same
>   key."

I tried to set the `EntityKey` to `null`, like it is in a new record; but it did not help. Any idea?

Comment: It sounds like theirs a duplicate PK somewhere. have you tried doing a where clause by key 1726526 in your db?

Comment: Yes; the highest existing key is 101626 in the DB

Comment: I think you are getting the error because of the child objects, you should try setting a new key for every child object.

Comment: @hazimdikenli make it an answer and I'll approve it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are getting the error because of the child objects, you should try setting a new key for every child object.

Answer (score 2):

This object is already tracked by EF.

You have to either modify its key or change its state to Modified.

```
Context.MyRepo.Entry(myRecord).State = EntityState.Modified;
```

and then save it.